# Twilio nodejs answer phone example not working

Tags: node.js, twilio

I am using the following code example: [RESPOND TO INCOMING PHONE CALLS IN NODE.JS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-respond-to-incoming-phone-calls-in-node-js?code-sample=code-respond-to-an-incoming-call-with-twiml&code-language=js&code-sdk-version=2.x)

I am using twilio package version 3.3.0.  The error I am receiving is twilio.TwimlResponse is not a constructor. Thoughts...Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Soooo, it never fails.  This was my first question and I knew as I was typing it this had to be something simple that I was missing :-/  Well, the example pages has a little link in the right corner for version.  Sure enough, the default version is 2.x.  Guess what happens when you click the 3.x example...It works!!!  Geez.  Oh well, at least I didn't waste a full day on it :-)  Thanks!